# How can I store divs content into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, store, addition

Hello this is my first post, i have been learning javascript for a week.
I want to make a little app that calculate how much do you spend on subscription per month.

You can add a new subscription with the name and the subscription price with two inputs --> and it creates 2 new div(one is subscriptionName the other is subscriptionPrice) they are store into a new div (newSubscription).

Now i would like to store all the subscriptionPrice var into an array and addition all of them.
(is it the right logic to apply ? maybe im wrong).

I also thought about doing the addition of the :

.abo-list > .abo:nth-child(1) > .abo-price

.abo-list > .abo:nth-child(1+1) > .abo-price

...

I have tried with this technic but the consol do not show even the first oneAboPrice.

```
 var pricesValues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < oneAboPrice.length; i++) {
    pricesValues.push(oneAboPrice[i].textContent);
}
console.log(pricesValues); /*dont show the values of every oneAboPrice*/
```

```js
//Selectors
const nameInput = document.querySelector('.name');
const price = document.querySelector('.price');
const validate = document.querySelector('.validate');
const abosList = document.querySelector('.abo-list');
const montantTotal = document.querySelector('.montant-total');


//event listeners 

validate.addEventListener('click', addAbo);
abosList.addEventListener('click', clickModify);


//functions
function addAbo(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //creating the NewAbo DIV
    const Abodiv = document.createElement('div');
    Abodiv.classList.add('abo');
    //creating a LI 
    const newAbo = document.createElement('li');
    newAbo.innerText = nameInput.value + ' ' ;
    newAbo.classList.add('abo-item');
    Abodiv.appendChild(newAbo);
    //creating a div Price of one Sub
    const oneAboPrice = document.createElement('div');
    oneAboPrice.classList.add('abo-price');
    oneAboPrice.innerText = price.value;
    Abodiv.appendChild(oneAboPrice);
    //modify button
    const modifyAbo = document.createElement('button');
    modifyAbo.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>';
    modifyAbo.classList.add('modifyAbo');
    Abodiv.appendChild(modifyAbo);
    //trash button
    const trashAbo = document.createElement('button');
    trashAbo.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>';
    trashAbo.classList.add("trashAbo");
    Abodiv.appendChild(trashAbo);
    //append to Abo-list
    abosList.appendChild(Abodiv);

    //total Amount of every newAboPrice

 
    //reset input value
    nameInput.value ="";
    price.value="";

    //store every .abo price (oneAboPrice)value into an array (this is where i need help)
    var pricesValues = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < oneAboPrice.length; i++) {
        pricesValues.push(oneAboPrice[i].textContent);
    }
    console.log(pricesValues); /*dont show the values of every oneAboPrice*/

    montantTotal.innerHTML = parseFloat(oneAboPrice.textContent); /* + oneAboPrice nth:child(2) + ....*/
}

function clickModify(e) {
    const item = e.target;
    //Delete newAbo
    if(item.classList[0] === "trashAbo"){
        const abo = item.parentElement;
    abo.remove();
    }
    //modify newAbo (To do)

}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Poppins&family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:wght@500&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.abo{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.abo li{
    flex: 1;
}
.fa-trash{
    pointer-events: none;
}

.abo-price{
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Gestionnaire d'abonnements</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="left">
            <p>Nom de l'abonnement</p><input type="text"  class="name" placeholder="netflix">
            <p>Prix mensuel</p><input type="number" class="price" placeholder="13,49">
            <input type="button" value="Valide" class="validate">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <h1>MES ABOS</h1>
            <ul class="abo-list">

            </ul>
            <p class="montant-total"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to show the array of **all items** using this loop:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < oneAboPrice.length; i++) {
    pricesValues.push(oneAboPrice[i].textContent);
}
```

The problem is, `oneAboPrice` is not the **all items** that you want, it's a new element that you just created with this code:

```js
//creating a div Price of one Sub
const oneAboPrice = document.createElement('div');
oneAboPrice.classList.add('abo-price');
oneAboPrice.innerText = price.value;
Abodiv.appendChild(oneAboPrice);
```

#### Solution

So, to correctly loop through **all items**, this is what the loop should be:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.abo-price').forEach(item => {
    pricesValues.push(parseFloat(item.innerHTML));
});
```

Let's me explain. `document.querySelectorAll('.abo-price')` will select all of your `oneAboPrice` at the time being. Then you can use `item.innerHTML` to get the text inside of each item, not `item.textContent`.

```js
//Selectors
const nameInput = document.querySelector('.name');
const price = document.querySelector('.price');
const validate = document.querySelector('.validate');
const abosList = document.querySelector('.abo-list');
const montantTotal = document.querySelector('.montant-total');


//event listeners 

validate.addEventListener('click', addAbo);
abosList.addEventListener('click', clickModify);


//functions
function addAbo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //creating the NewAbo DIV
  const Abodiv = document.createElement('div');
  Abodiv.classList.add('abo');
  //creating a LI 
  const newAbo = document.createElement('li');
  newAbo.innerText = nameInput.value + ' ';
  newAbo.classList.add('abo-item');
  Abodiv.appendChild(newAbo);
  //creating a div Price of one Sub
  const oneAboPrice = document.createElement('div');
  oneAboPrice.classList.add('abo-price');
  oneAboPrice.innerText = price.value;
  Abodiv.appendChild(oneAboPrice);
  //modify button
  const modifyAbo = document.createElement('button');
  modifyAbo.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>';
  modifyAbo.classList.add('modifyAbo');
  Abodiv.appendChild(modifyAbo);
  //trash button
  const trashAbo = document.createElement('button');
  trashAbo.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>';
  trashAbo.classList.add("trashAbo");
  Abodiv.appendChild(trashAbo);
  //append to Abo-list
  abosList.appendChild(Abodiv);

  //total Amount of every newAboPrice


  //reset input value
  nameInput.value = "";
  price.value = "";

  //store every .abo price (oneAboPrice)value into an array (this is where i need help)
  var pricesValues = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('.abo-price').forEach(item => {
    pricesValues.push(parseFloat(item.innerHTML));
  });

  console.log(pricesValues); /*dont show the values of every oneAboPrice*/

  montantTotal.innerHTML = parseFloat(oneAboPrice.textContent); /* + oneAboPrice nth:child(2) + ....*/
}

function clickModify(e) {
  const item = e.target;
  //Delete newAbo
  if (item.classList[0] === "trashAbo") {
    const abo = item.parentElement;
    abo.remove();
  }
  //modify newAbo (To do)

}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Poppins&family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:wght@500&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.abo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.abo li {
  flex: 1;
}

.fa-trash {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.abo-price {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Gestionnaire d'abonnements</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="left">
      <p>Nom de l'abonnement</p><input type="text" class="name" placeholder="netflix">
      <p>Prix mensuel</p><input type="number" class="price" placeholder="13,49">
      <input type="button" value="Valide" class="validate">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>MES ABOS</h1>
      <ul class="abo-list">

      </ul>
      <p class="montant-total"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete version

I know it is a lot different from your code, but it is all recommended methods

```js
//Selectors
const nameInput = document.querySelector('.name');
const price = document.querySelector('.price');
const validate = document.querySelector('.validate');
const abosList = document.querySelector('.abo-list');
const montantTotal = document.querySelector('.montant-total');


//event listeners 

validate.addEventListener('click', addAbo);
abosList.addEventListener('click', clickModify);

let abos = []; // the main array 

const render = () => {
  let sum = 0;
  abosList.innerHTML = abos.map(({name,price}) => { // grb the name and price from the object array
    sum += price; // sum it for the montantTotal
    // create an array of template literals
    return `<div class="abo"><li>${name}</li><div class="abo-price">${price}</div>
  <button type="button" class="modifyAbo"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></button>
  <button type="button" class="trashAbo"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
  </div>`
  }).join(""); // and join them with nothing

  montantTotal.innerHTML = sum.toFixed(2)

}

function addAbo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  abos.push({ name: nameInput.value, price: +price.value }); // create an array of names,prices 
  //reset input value
  nameInput.value = "";
  price.value = "";
  render(); // show the array
}

function clickModify(e) {
  const item = e.target.closest('button');
  //Delete newAbo
  if (item.classList.contains("trashAbo")) {
    const parent = item.closest('div')
    const name = parent.querySelector('li').textContent; // save the name
    parent.remove(); // before removing
    abos = abos.filter(item => item.name != name); // remove the object with the name from the array
  } else if (item.classList.contains("modifyAbo")) {
    const parent = item.closest('div');
    const aboName = parent.querySelector('li').textContent; // copy from the div
    const aboPrice = +parent.querySelector('.abo-price').textContent; // copy from the div 
    nameInput.value = aboName; // set the form values
    price.value = aboPrice;    // so they can be edited
    abos = abos.filter(item => item.name != aboName); // remove the abo so valide will add it back
  }
  render()
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Poppins&family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:wght@500&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.abo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.abo li {
  flex: 1;
}

.fa-trash {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.abo-price {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<title>Gestionnaire d'abonnements</title>
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>Nom de l'abonnement</p><input type="text" class="name" placeholder="netflix">
    <p>Prix mensuel</p><input type="number" class="price" placeholder="13,49">
    <input type="button" value="Valide" class="validate">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h1>MES ABOS</h1>
    <ul class="abo-list">

    </ul>
    <p class="montant-total"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your response this is  exactly the result i wanted ! you are doing magic ! do you think you can explain me your logic and comment a little bit more the code ? like i said I just start learning JavaScript. and i think I can learn a lot of what you just post as an answer. Thank you again.

Comment: I have a little problem, my css command doesn't work anymore : .fa-trash{
    pointer-events: none;
}

Comment: What was it supposed to do? I'll add some more comments

Comment: When I click on the trash button (on the trash icon more precisely) it delete all the subscription instead of deleting the one concerned. I did this command in order to avoid this error. In order to delete the concerned subscription i need to click everywhere in the button where the trash icon is not present. It is annoying.. Thanks again mister

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. If you run my code above, you can click the trash next to the abo and it will only delete that abo. You need all my code to make this work

Comment: in you snippet everything is working fine right now. When I paste into my code editor(visual studio code) and run it it works for the first manipulation then it bugs. I will try to put it online and see if it keeps makings this bugs

Comment: Sure - let me know

Comment: http://www.raphaelmatthey.fr/ everything is working perfectly fine. The bug was occuring when 2 sub of the same name where added and if one was deleted the other one was also deleted. Thank you for the comments on your code i will try to study this tomorow. Bye !

Comment: Yeah, the filter will delete all with same name

Answer (score 0):

If your only purpose is to get the total value of all subscriptions, you don't need an array. just call the function below every time a new subscription is added (call it inside `addAbo`).

```js
// this will select all the `div` items with the class `.abo-price`
const subscriptionEls = document.querySelectorAll('.abo-price');

function calculateTotal() {
  let total = 0;
 
  // loop through each '.abo-price' element
  subscriptionEls.forEach((el) => {
    const textValue = el.innerText; // '12,49' (string)
    const numericValue = parseInt(textValue); // 12,49 (number)
    total += numericValue; // add each numerical value to the total
  })

  montantTotal.innerText = total;
}
```